# Dell Poweredge R410, ubuntu(14.04) running dead slow

Tags: 14.04, dell, hardware, compatibility

I've have a machine, Dell Poweredge R410 with Ubuntu OS installed in. I'd no problem during installing, however, once it is done it has become annoying as performance is unforgivably abysmal. It runs dead slow that i have to keep typing in vigorously for entering as basic and short a word as password. The machine configuration is as follows:

Memory: 5.6 GiB;
Processor: Intel Xeon(R) CPU E5503 @ 2.00GHz X 4;
Graphics: Gallum 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.4, 128 bits);
OS Type: 64 bit;
Disk: 320 GB;

This runs slow in that if i open any application it opens with layer by layer and becomes solid only in a while. I hunch this is an issue with graphics.

Kindly,help me get it run faster to a degree acceptable or suggest me a different version of ubuntu or Linux that is compatible with the hardware. My intention is to use SQL on this machine, primarily.

Comment: Are you using a server image?

Comment: If the system is slow then it is waiting on something. Either on the CPU (unlikely, a E5503 is modern enough), disk, network, ...  To answer what it is waiting on you need to post more information.

Comment: @Hennes I've edited the question. please see to help me out.

Comment: *-pci:43
          description: Host bridge
          product: Xeon 5500/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller Channel 2 Rank Registers
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 12b
          bus info: pci@0000:ff:06.2
          version: 05
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz

Comment: I've installed 64 bit OS while the above data retrieved by running the command $lshw.

Comment: @belacqua Nope, that set of details was generated from system settings.

Comment: If this is primarily a server, running without a GUI environment (shell/command line only) should help....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install a lighter desktop environment like lxde or xfce (preferably lxde). Lxde is light on resources and will give you a faster performance than unity gives you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
However, can you rather suggest me lower versions of Ubuntu itself?
Reason being that i'm used to Ubuntu and would like to keep to it.

Comment: No I not telling you to go away from Ubuntu. Just telling you to install a separate environment within it. If you are  really used to Ubuntu, try installing Gnome classic Desktop environment, which is also low on resources.

Comment: Or you can also try reinstalling your copy of Ubuntu

Comment: Could you help me get Gnome classic installed . I've tried using the comment $ sudo apt-get install gnome-session-fallback.This wont work though. Please help me out.

Comment: You should use sudo apt-get install gnome-session-flashback

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar Issue
[ubuntu 14 painfully slow on dell r200](https://askubuntu.com/questions/475957/ubuntu-14-painfully-slow-on-dell-r200)

what i have found is you need to add some options to the boot loader
i use "mc" with "mcedit" (sudo su)
but edit

/etc/default/grub

change:

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
to
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nofb nomodeset"

hit f2 to save, and f10 to quit
then run

update-grub

and reboot

Comment: It did not work in my case. The machine was still very slow after reboot.