# ubuntu 14 painfully slow on dell r200

Tags: 14.04, ati, dell, radeon

I didn't notice it at first. The machines (there is 20 plus) are to be used a simple file servers. It wasn't until samba just wouldn't act right that I installed a desktop gui and started more diagnoseing the problem did I catch the slow preformance... I've tested 4 servers they all suck. And windows 7 runs fantastic on them. I have Google and searched. But nothing to explain this.

The easy test is dmesg is so slow you can almost read it.

I'm guessing it's an apic or cpu power management issue.

What output would you all like?????

It is a core2 machine with 4Gb of ram. On board data.

Comment: If you run `top` is there anything consuming significant CPU? What is CPU idle %?

Comment: Update:
In "recovery" kernel the dell poweredge r200 runs like it should.

Comment: @bain In recovery kernel 100%
also /proc/cpuinfo looks normal with cpu speed showing 2.8ghz and the "cpu Mhz" showing 2800

Comment: edit that didn't work: In recovery kernel 100%, in normal boot its 98~99
also /proc/cpuinfo looks normal with cpu speed showing 2.8ghz and the "cpu Mhz" showing 2800
In normal Kernel its showing some funky stuff
(hand typed)
processor 0
model name : Intel Core 2 Duo e7400 2.8Ghz
cpu MHZ : 1600.00

processor : 1
model name : Intel Core 2 Duo e7400 2.8Ghz
cpu MHZ: 2133.00

now i believe those numbers should change.

also i've run apt-get update; apt-get upgrade
and problem presists

Comment: acpi = off in grub  doesn't help....

Comment: I've now tryed ubuntu server on 5 yes 5 different R200s. same problem
ooo god its slower....
So i'm trying to kill all forms of graphics, framebuffer. and added 
nofb nomodeset quite splash
to grub, and now its even worse....

Comment: GETTING BETTER :-)
I just tried ( while typeing above)
GRUB_GFXMODE=test
and
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nofb nomodeset"

and now its running much better. like it should really.

Comment: In that case it sounds like a problem with the graphics. When it is going slow do you see any errors from `dmesg`? The Dell R200 has an onboard ATI ES1000, which is supposed to be [fully supported by the open source Radeon driver](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver). Can you post the output of `dmesg` and `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` on pastebin.com and post links here?

Comment: Which desktop are you using? ATI ES1000 has no 3D acceleration (only 2D), so if you are using Unity you can expect it to be slow. You could install Xubuntu, or since these are servers, you could disable Xorg entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Some years ago we had a machine that did the same thing. It was as if it ran at a tenth of it's actual clock speed. When we used the recovery kernel it was nice and fast, but it only recognised 1GB of memory. After compiling many many kernels and trying all sorts of things we eventually struck on the real problem: There is a bug in some intel chipsets where a piece of very slow memory right at the top isn't correctly mapped, and of course this is where the kernel is loaded, so the slowness was because the kernel was loaded into very slow ram.

The fix was to pass the mem= boot parameter and sacrifice a 100MB or RAM right at the top. This was also why the recovery kernel worked so well, it loaded the kernel below 1GB instead and avoided this block of memory.